# log4j how to log in to files having path according to date

Tags: java, file, log4j

I am using log4j for logging in my java program.I need to log contents in a path according to date.For example, I need an error log  as file name "error.log" and its path should be "log/13/6/11/error.log" when logging  date is 11/June/2013.How i create log4j property file according to the above requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Log4j` provides a `DailyRollingFileAppender` that does this job. You can configure to wrap up the current file and start logging to a new one based on date and/or time.

Your `log4j.properties` would look something like (among other things like *pattern*)

```
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=app.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

This would have rolled yesterday's file as `app.log.2013-06-10` while today's file would be `app.log`.

To name the files as `log/13/6/11/error.log` is **not** possible since *file names cannot contain path separators*. You may consider something like `app.log_13-6-11_error.log` as

```
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=app.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='_'yy-MM-dd'_error.log'
```

Your current file would then be named as `app.log`.

Comment: @sajith File names cannot contain path separators. Check update.

Comment: I need to save at the given path,not the file name

Comment: Ah, sorry to have misunderstood your question. I have a solution for that too. Check back later.

Comment: None of the rolling appenders in Log4j roll the log file location. They only support rolling log files. So, you have two options: (1) Init Log4j programmatically that enables you to roll log location *at every app restart* (if the day has changed) (2) Init Log4j programmatically *and* implement your own *custom* rolling appender that enables you to roll log location every day (without requiring an app restart). In short, there's no pure log4j properties solution to what you want to achieve. Are you comfortable with this? You'd have to init Log4j from a class that bootstraps your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not supported out of the box afaik. You can write your own appender or move the files with a simple script triggered by a cron job.